# Correct syntax to pass an argument to my parameter in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, script, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script:

```
function comparisonScriptAIX
    {
        Param(
            $sideToCheck
        )
            
    #contents of my script 
    #such as creating files
    #performing actions etc...  
    }

comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck
```

If I run this I get an error:

```
comparisonScriptAIX : Missing an argument for parameter 'sideToCheck'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again.
```

This makes sense as there is no argument provided to the paramater. If I change the code a bit like this:

```
comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck "Blabla"
```

It will run. Now, I want the script to run through the Task Scheduler and pass an argument, so I removed the "blablabla" from the script. I have created a task and that task runs the script properly when I do not inlcude "-sideToCheck". But when I do include "-sideToCheck", nothing is happening.

Program/script:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Add arguments (optional):

```
-NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File G:\Scripts\check_AIX.ps1 -sideToCheck "CMDB"
```

Now, I do not know the correct syntax to pass the argument of **CMDB** to the parameter of the Powershell script. Also I am not sure if the syntax in Powershell is correct.

Why is this not working, and how do I fix this?

**EDIT 13-12-2022:**

Based on the comments/answers I updated the script:

```
comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck $sideToCheck
```

And I also added the following line to use the log that is already in the script:

```
"$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : $($sideToCheck)" | Out-File -encoding ascii $errorLog -append
```

When I run this script within Powershell (so no task yet) the result in the log is the following:

```
2022-12-13 10:52:24 :
```

When I run it from the task scheduler, it looks the same:

```
2022-12-13 10:55:00 :
```

So the data (in my example "CMDB" is not yet passed to the script). I expect the following to see in the log:

```
2022-12-13 11:03:00 : CMDB
```

The script runs, but the value is not yet passed.

**EDIT 2**
Also tried:

```
        Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$sideToCheck
    )
```

Comment: Try to enclose the argument in quotes : `'-sideToCheck "CMDB"'`

Comment: That did, unfortunately, not work.

Comment: How about putting in your script like so `comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck $sideToCheck` where you have `$sideToCheck` omitted, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have this** in the [function](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html) in your script that you call which defines the function, what it does, and any parameters you define for it to use when called.

```
function comparisonScriptAIX
    {
        Param(
            $sideToCheck
        )
            
    #contents of my script 
    #such as creating files
    #performing actions etc...  
    }
```

**In this same script** which defines the function, you also call the function with the named parameter but you have left out the variable to pass to the function on that call.

When the script executes and calls the function it is not passing the value you set the parameter variable. Thus the error that it's missing at function execution time when called in the script.

**Change this**

```
comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck
```

**To be this**

```
comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck $sideToCheck
```

**To resolve** define the `param()` at the **top of the script** since you are passing that to the script to set it when `PowerShell -File` calls the script. It'll then reuse its value to pass to the function call within the script to give you the expected output.

**The full script** should look like this.

```
Param($sideToCheck);

function comparisonScriptAIX { 
    Param($sideToCheck)
    "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") : $($sideToCheck)" | Out-File -encoding ascii $errorLog;
    };
comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck $sideToCheck;
```

**Logic Screen Shot Breakdown**
[image]

**Execute it with PowerShell.exe** via this syntax:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File G:\Scripts\check_AIX.ps1 -sideToCheck "CMDB"
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Functions](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html)
- [Pass parameters to a PowerShell script](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-args.html)

  > **Param**
  >
  > To define arguments by name, use a param statement, which is a comma
  > separated list of variables, optionally prefixed with a [data type]
  > and/or with `=` default values.
  >
  > If used, the param statement MUST be the first thing in your
  > script or function:

Comment: Hello Vomit, I have changed the script (see EDIT in OP) but the value is not yet passed. The script however, runs. Do you know why the value is not passed to the script yet?

Comment: Also tried this in the scheduled task: -sideToCheck CMDB (so without the quotes) but that did not work either

Comment: @NiekJonkman I just updated the answer with fully confirmed and working logic. Give it a refresh and test the latest logic I provided. Because you are calling the script with the `-File` parameter, it was being set when the function was called but not the script. Adding that to the top of the script defines it and then allows it to be reused when you call the function in that script. Hopefully that gets you what you need, but let me know if you need additional help and I'll be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something called a `switch`.

You need to change your parameters to look like this:

```
function comparisonScriptAIX
{
    Param(
        [switch]$sideToCheck
    )
}
```

Here is how you call it:

```
comparisonScriptAIX -sideToCheck
```

Here is how you check for it:

```
if ($sideToCheck.IsPresent) {
    # yada yada
}
```

more info: if you are using powershell core, you can treat the `switch` like a `boolean`. this also works:

```
if ($sideToCheck) {
    # yada yada
}
```

here is the link to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: If I use a switch, the default value inside $sideToCheck is "true" , where I expect it to be "CMDB".